# Why some objects won't show and selectable in Cryptomatte?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, meta-objects, cryptomatte, metaballs

I have created some metalballs and animated them, and I need them to get excluded and masked in Composition, but I can't select them in any kind of matte: asset, material or object

The problem gets solved if I delete them and create new one; but I can't, because they got lots of animations and other things connected to them in main scene.

Is there anything maybe I've forgot or accidentally unchecked about them?!

[Picture below shows the picker in window that selects Plane behind the Meta!]

[image]

.

Blender File:
[Download file with problem here in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1La9OHtFoWge-U5m_8_G_EvdRYBGcWq5g/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: I doubt this will get solved unless you share a file with the problem. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Link to download the file added below the image. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what I may changed in my material for that Meta object (Cloud object), but seems like the problem solved by copying all texture nodes into a new Material, re-setting up the Principal shader node and re-connetting all texture nodes there.
Now my cloud objects shows up in all three Cryptomatte options, Asset, Object and Material.